# options_from_collection_for_select error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to post all the group locations in my table of group locations.  The thing is I don't want to post the id's in the select tag I want the names to show up.  I have tried several iterations and nothing works.  Instead of posting all the code here I already have the relevant code and error in a gist on github:

https://gist.github.com/codejoy/19be7b182e372dd98e76

There error is posted there...  basically I just want what I thought was something simple (even if my models are a bit complex in their relationships).  I just cannot figure out what this error is telling me, if i switch this line:

```
<%= select_tag "group_providers", options_from_collection_for_select(GroupLocation.all, 'id' ,@group_locations.map{ |j| j.dba }), :multiple => true%>
```

To this:

```
<%= select_tag "group_providers", options_from_collection_for_select(GroupLocation.all, 'id' ,@group_locations.map{ |j| j.id }), :multiple => true%>
```

The error changes to this:

> TypeError in Providers#add_location Showing
>   /vagrant/ipanmv2/app/views/providers/add_location.html.erb where line
>
> ## 51 raised:
>
> [2] is not a symbol nor a string Extracted source (around line #51):
>   48 49 50 51 52 53 54
>
> ```
>              <tr>
>                <td>          
>                  <% if @group_locations.count >0 %>
>                    <%= select_tag "group_providers", options_from_collection_for_select(GroupLocation.all, 'id'
> ```
>
> ,@group_locations.map{ |j| j.id }), :multiple => true%>
>                        <% else %>
>                          <%= select_tag "group_providers", "Add new...".html_safe, :multiple => true, :style => "width:
>   300px" %>
>                        <% end %>
>
> Rails.root: /vagrant/ipanmv2
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>   app/views/providers/add_location.html.erb:51:in
>   `_app_views_providers_add_location_html_erb__410977632_87411510'
>   Request
>
> Parameters:
>
> {"id"=>"4"} Toggle session dump Toggle env dump Response
>
> Headers:
>
> None

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation for [`options_from_collection_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select), you'll see that it expects the third parameter to be the method used for the option text value. Using the `map` method here returns an array of your group location IDs which is neither a string or a symbol, hence the error.

If you just want to have the option text to be the value of the `dba` attribute try this instead:

`<%= select_tag "group_providers", options_from_collection_for_select(@group_locations, :id, :dba), :multiple => true %>`